# pasar una variable por un enlace y autocompletar un formulario en laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentado pasar una varible por un enlace y este a su vez me lleva a un formulario. Dicho formulario tiene un input, y en ese input necesito llenarlo con ese variable que pase por el enlace. Estoy reutilizando el formulario del registro solo que ahi le hago un condicional. Si la variable tiene contenido pues muestro el input con la variable y la desabilito pero si no, entonces muestro el input para ser ingresado por el usuario.

Lo he intentado pero siempre me lleva al sitio donde estoy y no al formulario.

mi codigo es el siguiente:

archivo donde esta el enlace para llevarme al formulario. dejo la parte comentada  **master-vendor.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="AnthonCode Admin Panel.">
    <meta name="author" content="AnthonCode">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{url('/')}}/assets/images/{{$settings[0]->favicon}}" />

    <title>{{$settings[0]->title}} - Tablero del Vendedor</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/octicons/3.5.0/octicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/genius-admin.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{!! url('admin/dashboard') !!}">
                    <img class="logo" src="{!! url('assets/images/logo') !!}/{{$settings[0]->logo}}" alt="LOGO">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">

            <!--este es el enlace que me lleva al formulario con la variable-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="{{route('vendor.reg.referido', $codigo=Auth::user()->codigo_propio)}}"
                        target="_blank">Codigo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <b
                            class="fa fa-angle-down"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{!! url('vendor/vendorprofile') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Editar
                                perfil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{!! url('vendor/vendorpassword') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Cambio de
                                contraseña</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Cerrar sesion
                            </a>

                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{!! url('vendor/dashboard') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Tablero</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{!! url('mlm') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Grafico MLM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{!! url('vendor/orders') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-usd"></i> Ordenes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{!! url('vendor/products') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> Productos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{!! url('vendor/withdraws') !!}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i> Retirar</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        @yield('content')

    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Switchery -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/plugin/nicEdit.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/admin-genius.js')}}"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

$('#grid').DataTable( {

  "responsive": true,

  "pagingType": "full_numbers",

  "language": {

    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",

    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",

    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",

    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",

    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",

    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",

    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",

    "sInfoPostFix":    "",

    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",

    "sUrl":            "",

    "sInfoThousands":  ",",

    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",

    "oPaginate": {

      "sFirst":    "Primero",

      "sLast":     "Último",

      "sNext":     "Siguiente",

      "sPrevious": "Anterior"

    },

    "oAria": {

      "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",

      "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"

    }


  },

  "iDisplayLength": 5,
  "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15], [5, 10, 15]]

} );

});
    </script>

    <script>
        $("#maincats").change(function () {
        $("#subs").html('<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>');
        $("#subs").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#childs").html('<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>');
        $("#childs").attr('disabled',true);
        var mainid = $(this).val();
        $.get('{{url('/')}}/subcats/'+mainid, function(response){
            $("#subs").attr('disabled',false);
            $.each(response, function(i, cart){
                $.each(cart, function (index, data) {
                    $("#subs").append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</option>');
                    //console.log('index', data)
                })
            })
        });
    });
    $("#subs").change(function () {
        $("#childs").html('<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>');
        $("#childs").attr('disabled',true);
        var mainid = $(this).val();
        $.get('{{url('/')}}/childcats/'+mainid, function(response){
            $("#childs").attr('disabled',false);
            $.each(response, function(i, cart){
                $.each(cart, function (index, data) {
                    $("#childs").append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</option>');
                    //console.log('index', data)
                })
            })
        });
    });

    </script>
    @yield('footer')
</body>

</html>
```

archivo rutas **web.php**

```
Route::get('/vendor/registration', 'Auth\VendorRegistrationController@showRegistrationForm')->name('vendor.reg');
Route::get('/vendor/registration/{codigo}', 'Auth\VendorRegistrationController@showRegistrationReferido')->name('vendor.reg.referido');
```

controlador **VendorRegistrationController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Vendors;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class VendorRegistrationController extends Controller
{

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:vendor');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('vendor.registration');
    }
    //este es el codigo que estoy realizando
    public function showRegistrationReferido($codigo)
    {
        $cod = $codigo;
        return view('vendor.registration', compact('cod'));
    }
}
```

este es el archivo del formulario **registration.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple Documentation for project NewsOcean.">
    <meta name="author" content="AnthonCode">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{$settings[0]->title}} - Registro - Vendedor</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/genius-admin.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    @inject('departamentos', 'App\Services\Departamentos')
    <section id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="">
                        <h1>Registro de comerciante</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-center" id="res" style="display: none;"></div>

                        <form action="{{route('vendor.reg.submit')}}" method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="name" placeholder="Nombre del del vendedor" class="form-control"
                                            type="text" required>
                                        <p id="nameError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="phone" placeholder="Número de teléfono" class="form-control"
                                            type="text" required>
                                        <p id="nameError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- si la variable tiendo codigo muestra el input completado -->
                            @if($cod)
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="codigo_referente" minlength="4" maxlength="4" disabled
                                            placeholder={{$cod}} class="form-control" type="text">
                                        <p id="nameError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @else
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="codigo_referente" minlength="4" maxlength="4"
                                            placeholder="Codigo de referente" class="form-control" type="text">
                                        <p id="nameError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="id_departamento" id="departamento"
                                            onchange="loadCiudad()">

                                            @foreach ($departamentos->get() as $index => $departamento)
                                            <option value="{{ $index }}"
                                                {{ old('id_departamento') == $index ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                                {{$departamento}}
                                            </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="id_ciudad" class="form-control" id="ciudad">

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="email"
                                            required>
                                        <p id="emailError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control"
                                            type="password" required>
                                        <p id="passError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña"
                                            class="form-control" type="password" required>
                                        <p id="passError" class="errorMsg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="resp" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>* {{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>* {{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>* {{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                                @if(Session::has('message'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                    {{ Session::get('message') }}
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="submit" id="admin_btn" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block"
                                        value="Registrar">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center login">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                    <a href="{{route('vendor.login')}}" class="text-center">¿Ya tienes cuenta?
                                        Ingresar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="forget" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forget-modal">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a> -->
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <footer id="footer" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;
                    <p>2019 Desarollado por <strong><a href="{{url('/')}}"
                                target="_blank">{{$settings[0]->title}}</a></strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
</body>
<script>
    function loadCiudad() {
            console.log('loadCiudad');

            var id_departamento = $('#departamento').val();
            console.log(id_departamento);


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/api/ciudades",
                    data: {id_departamento:id_departamento},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#ciudad').empty();
                        $('#ciudad').append("<option value=''>Seleccione una ciudad</option>");
                        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                            const element = data[index];
                            $('#ciudad').append("<option value='" + element.id_ciudad + "'>" + element.nombre + "</option>");
                        }
                    },
                });


        }
        loadCiudad();

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema recide en los nombres de las rutas y el valor que pasas como parámetro,
las rutas tienen el mismo nombre a diferencia que una espera un parámetro, pero tu dices que a veces ese parámetro es un valor vacío, por lo cual la ruta quedaría como la primera, por ejemplo

`/vendor/registration` => primera ruta.

`/vendor/registration/test` => segunda ruta, pero si el valor es vacío queda como la primera `/vendor/registration`

pero la solución es simple como estas usando el mismo código en las dos funciones de controlador puedes hacer

```
public function showRegistrationForm(Request $request)
{
    $codigo = $request->codigo;
    return view('vendor.registration', compact('codigo');
}
```

Luego para crear la url

```
route('vendor.reg.referido',['codigo' => $codigo=Auth::user()->codigo_propio]);
```

Comment: me sigue pasando igual. me deja en la misma vista donde estoy.